# Angular 7 Reactive Form Dropdown Options Are Not Updating

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

This is an example code
On Initial load drop, ng form down values is shown.

HTML code

```html
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
    <select formControlName="controlerName">
        <option *ngFor="let option of controlValues" [value]="option.id"> 
            {{option.values}}
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Ts file

```js
this.controlValues = [{id: "1", values: "1"}, {id: "2", values: "2"}] ..so on
this.testForm.controls['controlerName'].setValue(this.controlValues[0].values);
```

On button click

```js
this.controlValues = [{id: "1", values: "a"}, {id: "2", values: "b"}] ..so on
this.testForm.controls['controlerName'].setValue(this.controlValues[0].values);
```

but in the dropdown, it is showing the same previous values. but the variable is getting updated values.
Note: It is just a sample code. Where suppose not place exact code.
Data values not using subscribe. this.controlValues variable values need to be changed in HTML dropdown.

Comment: Can you please format your code correctly, so it is way more readable ?
And/or paste some code chunks, otherwise it's hard to give you an answer.

Comment: Perchance because you're using `[value]="option.value_id"` where it should be `[value]="option.id"`?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer updated value is showing in this.controlValues but dropdown values are not refreshed to new values and [value]="option.id"

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz to replicate this behavior? It seems unlikely that Angular wouldn't detect the changes.

Comment: I tested your code in Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hb9ad2. It works correctly and changes the select options every time.

Comment: @KariF. but i have to set the values and update the set values..because the values come from other component..the values are coming fine from other component but once click on the button it not updating

Comment: @KariF.I have a other dropdown each value of dropdown i get different json that has to update on other dropdown.. Values are getting properly but not updating

Comment: Sorry, you have to provide more code because the code you have posted works as it is.

Comment: @KariF. I should not provide more code. But i can explain like. we have two drop downs in different component on one drop down value click there the other drop down in other component need to update..when i console the value on click it showing correctly but values on second drop down not updated. If can please help on it. It will be great. My research and understanding DOM is loaded fast and before the values reach. Is there any work around on this? how to load after data get on each value click on first drop down

Comment: So you select a value from DropDownOne in ComponentOne. Then you want the available values for DropDownTwo in ComponentTwo to be updated. Is that correct? If so then you should show some code explaining how the components are interacting. Do they communicate using input binding? Or shared service? O some other mechanism?

Comment: @KariF. Yes select a value from DropDownOne in ComponentOne. Then you want the available values for Drop DownTwo in Component Two to be updated. Components communicate with import other component then call the function by declaring in constructor and getting values. Is it clear how they communicate? The application is routing app

Comment: @KariF. This is why we need more code. Had we known that from the start this whole process would of been a lot less painful. You should not directly importing a component inside another component to share values. Values should be shared via `@Input()`, `@Output()` or a common service. You can try manually trigger change detection `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`. see https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I realized problem starts to occur after I imported BrowserAnimationsModule to my app module . Select dropdown value was not updating on view although selection reflects internally.

```
@Component({animations: [trigger('', [])]}
```

adding this seems to fix the issue